# How do I add images in questions?

Tags: support, image, posts

How do I add JPEG images in Ask Ubuntu questions?

Comment: Thank you for improving my english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ask Ubuntu has a built-in image uploader:

[image]

If you use it with [less than 10 reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/new-user), it will add them as *links* to your post; this is to prevent [abuse](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268469/4751173). However, you can hope another user will convert them to properly inlined images.

Comment: If I'm not awfully mistaken, new users (<10 rep) also can use the built-in image uploader. For new users, instead of an embedded image, only an i.stack.imgur.com link to the image would be added. Other users can then embed it easily. So no need to manually upload it to somewhere else first.

Comment: Thank you dear Mr. Glorfindel. I tried out your proposal but IMGUR would take only one of these two images.

Comment: @pomsky that could very well be the case, but I can't test it (without creating a new account). Perhaps the OP here can report back if that works?

Comment: @Glorfindel I also cannot verify myself, but do check the [second answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307503) posted to the meta SO question you linked. Also as a circumstantial evidence, I personally keep seeing questions from 'new users' regularly with i.stack.imgur.com links, which seems too good to be a coincidence.

Comment: @pomsky you've convinced me, thanks a lot!